# Как увеличить четкость заднего фона элемента

Tags: html, css

Что я делал:

Нарисовал картинку для заднего фона кнопки

Сжал картинку, так как она оказалась слишком большая для кнопки

Установил картинку в качестве заднего фона: `background: url("textures/menu.png") 0 0 no-repeat;`

Что получилось:

Впринципе, все впорядке, вот только картинка, естественно, отображается в плохом качестве, так как я ее сжимал. Нет ли способа улучшить качество картинки, ну или поместить ее в кнопку в качестве заднего фона при этом не сжимая?

Comment: А не вариант сжать менее сильно?

Comment: Не помещается в кнопку

Comment: А как вы сжимаете? Просто уменьшаете разрешение? Вы можете поместить картинку при помощи background-size: contain; или background-size: cover; как написали вам в ответе

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как вариант - используйте:

`{background-size: contain;}`.

В сокращенной форме:

```
{background: url("textures/menu.png") center / contain no-repeat;}
```